# If I allocate an a array of objects with operator new[] in C++ but deallocate them individually does it still constitute a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I know one is supposed to not mix and match new[] with delete and vice versa (delete[] with new). So

```
int* k = new int[5];
delete k;
```

is flawed as it will not free the allocated array. But is the following wrong?

```
int *k = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    delete k[i];
```

by wrong I mean - will it actually cause a memory leak or undefined behavior?

EDIT** My bad, what I meant to type was this:

```
int** k = new int*[5];
memset(k, 0, sizeof(int*)*5);

k[3] = new int;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (k[i])
    {
        delete k[i];
        k[i] = 0;
    }
```

In the above, the block of 5 places is never actually freed unless i call delete[] on `k` itself, though I can new/delete manage the ints inside of it.

Comment: Interesting point, but I can say for sure that I'll never be able to think of a situation where it helps to use it like this. I'm not sure what the answer is, as it looks like it would work in theory, but I believe `new[]` internally stores the number of items, and maybe other things somewhere in that memory.

Comment: It will not cause a memory leak or UB because it will not compile.

Comment: There is a language mechanism to separate memory allocation and object construction into two steps, so you can destroy individual objects but not the memory that backs it. It's called [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new), and it's what `std::vector` uses under the hood to allocate memory for the array without creating any objects. However, you have to code very carefully to use it without problems. You might as well use `std::vector` itself.

Comment: You're correct about the code after the EDIT.  `delete k[i];` correctly matches the `k[3] = new int;` statement (scalar new and scalar delete).  But it's "missing" a separate `delete[] k;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`k[i]` is an `int`, so it's **syntactically invalid** to call `delete` on it. The compiler should raise an error.

Even if you could, it would result in undefined behavior (saying you have an array of pointers which you allocate with `new[]` and attempt to delete it with `delete`). Mixing `new[]` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete` results in UB.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix-and-match either way. If you do, you have undefined behaviour (§5.3.5/2):

> **In the first alternative** (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a **pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression***, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **In the second alternative** (*delete array*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value or a **pointer value that resulted from a previous array *new-expression***. If not, the behavior is undefined.

(bold emphasis is mine)