# Overloading new

Tags: c++, new-operator, undefined-behavior, delete-operator

```
class myClass
{
    //variables etc.
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size);
};
```

1. Why overloaded `new` requires `size_t` argument? 
   I know that `malloc` requires size, but we can use `sizeof(myClass)` instead.
2. Can I mix `new[]` / `delete` and `new` / `delete[]` using this class? Are there any drawbacks of this?

```
class myClass
{
    //variables etc.
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        return new myClass[1];
    }
    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        delete[] (myClass*)(p);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your overloaded new will also be used for classes that derive from myClass, so sizeof(myClass) would not always be correct.

Comment: Who's to say you're going to use `new` in your implementation of your overloaded `new`.  You very well may use `malloc(size)` and `free` for the delete.

Comment: Ad 2. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692176/1741542

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `new[]` and `delete[]` in the implementation, you should either use `malloc`/`free` or prefix the cooresponding method with a scope, e.g.

```
class myClass {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
};
```